# Como obtener un String que viene dentro de un objeto entre llaves?

Tags: java, json, array, objeto

Tengo el siguiente objeto, que cunado accedo a el me devuelve lo siguiente:

```html
Map<String,Integer> getObtenerCanalCodigo();

{SXME=3, MVVI=9, APP8=8, CC=2, MVL=6, POS=5, WWW=1}
```

Como le hago para obtener en un String el canal "CC" o cualquier otro?

Comment: https://jarroba.com/map-en-java-con-ejemplos/

Answer (score 1):

Llamando al método **toString()** después de obtener el valor de la clave del mapa "CC" o cualquier otro. A continuación te indico un ejemplo:

```
public String getObtenerCanalCodigo(final String codigoCanal) {
    if (map.containsKey(codigoCanal)) {
        return map.get(codigoCanal).toString();         
    }
    return "El canal indicado no se encuentra disponible";
}
```